# Using WebDriver from Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium-webdriver

I try to include selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar in my Tomcat webapp, but Tomcat says:

```
validateJarFile([path to jar]) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

So I googled around and saw this on the Selenium website:

> You may, or may not, need the Selenium Server, depending on how you
>   intend to use Selenium-WebDriver. If you will be only using the
>   WebDriver API you do not need the Selenium-Server. If your browser and
>   tests will all run on the same machine, and your tests only use the
>   WebDriver API, then you do not need to run the Selenium-Server;
>   WebDriver will run the browser directly.

I just need WebDriver... Where do I get this from so that I can use it in my webapp without the server caused conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required download is the client side library, e.g. selenium-java-2.33.0.zip from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

> The Java bindings for Selenium 2, including the WebDriver API and the
>   Selenium RC clients. Download this if you plan on just using the
>   client-side pieces of Selenium

The description on the main http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ page doesn't really make this clear IMO

> In order to create scripts that interact with the Selenium Server
>   (Selenium RC, Selenium Remote Webdriver) or create local Selenium
>   WebDriver script you need to make use of language-specific client
>   drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This jar should be launched on the machine you wist to test on, not the
application server.

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers